# Gcloud and Kubectl see me logged in as two different users

Tags: macos, gcloud, kubectl

Mac here, in case it makes a difference. I am on 2 separate GCP/gcloud/GKE/Kubernetes projects and have two different gmails for each of them:

- Project 1: flim-flam, where my email is myuser1@gmail.example.com (pretend its a gmail)
- Project 2: foo-bar, where my email is myuser2@gmail.example.com

I log into my `myuser1@gmail.example.com` account via `gcloud auth login` and confirm I am logged in as that account. For instance, I go to the GCP console and verify (in the UI) that I am in fact logged in as `myuser1@gmail.example.com`. Furthermore, when I run `gcloud config configurations list` I get:

```
NAME       IS_ACTIVE  ACCOUNT                    PROJECT        COMPUTE_DEFAULT_ZONE  COMPUTE_DEFAULT_REGION
flim-flam  True       myuser1@gmail.example.com  flim-flam
foo-bar    False      myuser2@gmail.example.com  foo-bar
```

From my `flim-flam` project, when I run `kubectl delete ns flimflam-app` I get permission errors:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): namespace "flimflam-app" is forbidden: User "myuser2@gmail.example.com" cannot delete resource "namespaces" in API group "" in the namespace "flimflam-app": requires one of ["container.namespaces.delete"] permission(s).
```

So gcloud thinks I'm logged in as `myuser1` but kubectl thinks I'm logged in as `myuser2`. **How do I fix this?**

Comment: Why the DV? Question was on topic, not a dupe and was fully reproducible. Consider removing the DV and providing a comment with a suggestion for improvement instead. My questions are top notch here on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gcloud` and `kubectl` share user identities but their configuration is in different files.

Using `gcloud auth login` does not update (!) existing (!) `kubectl` configurations. The former (on Linux) are stored in `${HOME}/.config/gcloud` and the latter in `${HOME}/.kube/config`.

I don't have a copy on hand but, if you check `${HOME}/.kube/config`, it likely references the other Google account. You can either duplicate the `users` entry and reference it from the `context`. Or you could edit the existing `users` entry.

Actually, better yet use `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` to update `kubectl`'s configuration with the currently-active `gcloud` user. This command updates `${HOME}/.kube/config` for you.